# Can a PhD from a non-TU9 German university become a professor in a TU9 university?

Tags: phd, germany, habilitation

Suppose, someone does a PhD and a Habilitation from a non TU9 university.

Is there any practical barrier for him to become a professor in a TU9 university?

Comment: Yes, maybe not straight away, it depends on the quality of the research, but there are lots of examples where professors have upscaled from lesser universities.

Comment: What is a TU9 university?

Comment: [TU9 German Universities of Technology e. V. is the alliance of nine leading Technical Universities in Germany.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TU9)

Comment: Got my PhD from U Bremen, got tenured at TU Braunschweig, so: Yes to the question in the title (and "not entirely sure" to the question in the body).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Of course you can.** Otherwise their pool for hiring would be awfully small.

But don't take my word for it. To provide some evidence we can look at a department at one of the TU9 universities. For example the [Computer Science Department of TU Darmstadt](https://www.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/fb20/organisation_fb20/professuren_und_gruppenleitungen/index.en.jsp) (mainly because I'm somewhat familiar with it)

If we look at the list of full professors and eliminate those that have non-German doctorates, we are left with 18 Professors, 9 of which did not receive their degree from one of the TU9. (Though in practical terms almost none of them did, as the TU9 was only established in 2003.)

- **Carsten Binning [TU Darmstadt](http://tubiblio.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de/105180/)**
- <s>Christian Bischof [Cornell](https://ecommons.cornell.edu/handle/1813/6779)</s>
- Johannes Buchmann [Universität zu Köln](http://d-nb.info/830848258)
- <s>Dieter W. Fellner [TU Graz](http://www.gris.tu-darmstadt.de/home/members/fellner/11-03-09_Vitae_Fellner_EN_Endversion.pdf)</s>
- Marc Fischlin [Goethe-Universität Frankfurt am Main](https://www.math.uni-frankfurt.de/~dmst/research/phdtheses/mfischlin.dissertation.2001.pdf)
- <s>Johannes Fürnkranz [TU Wien](http://www.ke.tu-darmstadt.de/staff/juffi/cv.pdf)</s>
- Iryna Gurevych [Universität Duisburg-Essen](https://d-nb.info/971486220/34)
- **Reiner Hähnle [Universität Karlsruhe](https://tubiblio.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de/101360/)**
- **Matthias Hollick [TU Darmstadt](http://tuprints.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de/591/1/phd-thesis-matthias-hollick.pdf)**
- <s>Stefan Katzenbeisser [TU Wien](http://repositum.tuwien.ac.at/obvutwhs/download/pdf/1562445?originalFilename=true)</s>
- Kristian Kersting [Universität Freiburg](http://d-nb.info/983957975)
- **Andreas Koch [TU Braunschweig](https://www.esa.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/twiki/pub/Staff/AndreasKochPublications/1997_koch-diss.pdf)**
- Heiko Mantel [Universität des Saarlandes](https://publikationen.sulb.uni-saarland.de/bitstream/20.500.11880/25771/1/HeikoMantel_ProfDrJoergHSiekmann.pdf)
- Mira Mezini [Universität Siegen](http://www.digibib.net/permalink/467/UBSI-x/HBZ:HT009215031)
- **Max Mühlhäuser [Universität Karlsruhe](http://d-nb.info/870902466)**
- <s>Jan Peters [University of Southern California](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1329838)</s>
- Christian Reuter [Universität Siegen](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-658-08586-5)
- <s>Stefan Roth [Brown University](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1354820)</s>
- Ahmad-Reza Sadeghi [Universität des Saarlandes](https://publikationen.sulb.uni-saarland.de/bitstream/20.500.11880/25783/1/SadeghiAhmadReza_ProfDrBirgitPfitzmann.pdf)
- Thomas Schneider [Ruhr-Universität Bochum](http://www-brs.ub.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/netahtml/HSS/Diss/SchneiderThomas/diss.pdf)
- <s>Neerja Suri [University of Massechusetts, Amherst](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=170943)</s>
- **Orkar von Stryk [Technische Universität München](http://d-nb.info/942776429)**
- **Michael Waidner [Universität Karlsruhe](http://d-nb.info/930097238)**
- **Karsten Weihe [TU Berlin](http://d-nb.info/943509645)**
- **Felix Wolf [RWTH Aachen](http://d-nb.info/966513118)**

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can become professor at a TU9 university with a PhD from a non-TU9 university.

- There is no formal difference between PhDs from different universities in Germany.
- There is far from universal agreement in Germany that TU9 are the 'better' or 'elite' universities. Their main distinguishing factor is their focus on engineering subjects. The German ['Universities of Excellence' (*Exzellenzunis*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Universities_Excellence_Initiative) would be a better approximation of `German elite universities', but even for them the institution granting the PhD would not matter.
- In general the differences in reputation between universities in Germany is smaller than e.g. in the US or in France
- I know of several concrete cases of TU9 professors with non-TU9 PhDs.

Comment: Actually, I never heard of TU9 and my working grouped (physics) even accepts and promotes engineering students..